# Проблема с нахождением простых чисел

Tags: java, массивы, простые-числа

Я не очень понимаю в чем проблема я пытаюсь найти в массиве простые числа

```java
public void prostie() { 
    int n[] = {1, 3, 14, 10, 55, 7, 0, 9}; // создаю массив
    int a=4;//присваиваю 4 
    for (int i =1 ; i < n.length; i++) { //перебираю весь массив
        if ( n[i] < a ); // если массив меньше  числа 4 то это простое число так как 1 2 и 3 простые числа   
        System.out.println(n[i]); //  
        if ( (n[i] % 2 != 0) || (n[i] % 3 != 0) ); // если не делятся на 2 и на 3 то это простое число     
        System.out.println(n[i]); 
    }          
}
```

Comment: Не надо ставить `;` после обоих `if()`

Comment: `55` - это простое число ?

Comment: для начала: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE :)
если вы подразумеваете под `простым числом` что-то своё, добавьте описание

Answer (score 1):

Вы думаете, простые числа - это те, которые не делятся на два и на три?

```
else if ( (n[i] % 2 != 0) && (n[i] % 3 != 0) && (n[i] % 5 != 0) )
```

Индексация массива начинается с нуля.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант для данного массива будет такой:

```
if ((n[i] == 1) || (n[i] == 3) || (n[i] == 7)) {
   System.out.println(n[i]);
}
```

Это можно сократить до

```
System.out.println(1);
System.out.println(3);
System.out.println(7);
```

Comment: подскажите ,пожалуйста почему не работает код

Comment: int n[] = {1, 3, 14, 10, 55, 7, 0, 9};
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            if ((n[i] % 2 != 0) & (n[i] % 3 != 0) & (n[i] % 5 != 0)&(n[i]==3)||(n[i]==2))
                System.out.println("Nr prim" + n[i]);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Так посмотрите на условия. Для какого числа они должны сработать? Вы их наугад пишете?

Comment: у меня есть массив   int n[] = {1, 3, 14, 10, 55, 7, 0, 9};и я не знаю как вывести 3 так как 3 это тоже простое число но оно делиться на 3    int n[] = {1, 3, 14, 10, 55, 7, 0, 9}; for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) { if ((n[i] % 2 != 0) & (n[i] % 3 != 0) & (n[i] % 5 != 0)&(n[i]==3) ну я и написала что если в массиве есть 3 то пусть  выведит мне это число,но к сожалению код не работает